# Is ok to release my object after I call performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsobject

Memory management is being done manually, ARC is not used in this project..

The message object is created using `alloc` `init` and the code below is being called on background thread.

I pass a message object before the following call:

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(serverConnectionResult:) withObject: message waitUntilDone:NO];
```

After the call I want to do:

```
 [message release];
```

I am confused whether I should do this, because I am concerned whether the message object will be always valid when `serverConnectionResult` is called?  Is the method call `performSelectorOnMainThread` retaining the message object itself?  What's the rule to know that the called method retains my passed object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to do this. `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` will retain both the target of the message and the object. Similarly `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` will also retain the target and the object.

Comment: Thanks, what exactly is the rule to know that called functions/method will retain or not ?

Comment: @HotLicks I checked the docs for this method before posting, this is not mentioned in the method documentation that this method retains the passed object.

Comment: Check the docs again for the general topic of "memory management". To save you a couple seconds, here's what you should be reading: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Grand Central Dispatch and use `dispatch_async` on the main thread and pass in a block that calls your method and afterwards releases the message.